# Using gradient descent and Newton's method combined

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson, gradient-descent

I have this function $f(\mathrm{X})$ where $\mathrm{X=A+B+C}$ where $\mathrm{A}$ is a diagonal element with variable $a$ on its diagonal. $\mathrm{B}$ is another diagonal matrix with variable $b$ on its diagonal. $\mathrm{C}$ is a positive definite matrix with variable $c_{ij}$. Now I want to optimize this function over these variables. I was wondering to keep $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{B}$ constant first optimize over $\mathrm{C}$ using Newton's method. Then I will keep $\mathrm{C}$ constant and optimize over $a$ and $b$ using gradient descent.

I am not sure if this is applicable or will work. Suggestions guys?

Comment: What is motivating you to use two different methods?

Comment: @Tpofofn. I have Newton's method implementation that guarantees positive definiteness. And gradient descent over the other variable such that they are greater than equal to 0 will guarantee positive definiteness. I am not sure how I will guarantee positive definiteness if I optimize over $c_{ij}$

Comment: It sounds like you should formulate your problem as a semidefinite program, then solve it using a method tailored for SDPs, like an interior point method.  Good software is available, such as CVX in Matlab.

Comment: @littleO. I have log(det(X)) term in the function. I am not sure if this satisfied the criteria for semidefinite programming?

Comment: Maybe not exactly a semidefinite program, but I still think there's a good chance that an interior point method would be the standard way to solve your problem, and perhaps it could be done without too much trouble in CVX.  $\log(\det X)$ is a function often encountered in convex optimization.  Can you write out your optimization problem explicitly?

Comment: @littleO. My objective function is $-\frac{1}{2}y^TXy + X^{-1} + log(det(X))$

Comment: @user34790 Is the term $X^{-1}$ correct?  It's a matrix, but I thought it should be a scalar.  Also, what exactly are the constraints on $X$?

Comment: @littleO. Yeah it is $X^{-1}$ and the constraints on X is that it should be positive definite

Comment: @user34790 but how can the matrix $X^{-1}$ be added to the scalar $-\frac12 y^T Xy$?  Seems like an error.

Comment: @littleO. Yeah it was $r^TX^{-1}r$ where you can treat r as a constant vector

Comment: @littleO any suggestions?

Comment: This is smooth constrained minimization. There's no need for CVX. If you use gradient search or Newton's method with an appropriate backtracking line search you will preserve positive definiteness. There is no need to build a hybrid method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm dropping that $\tfrac{1}{2}$ for simplicity; it can be buried in the $y$ vector. Assuming the function is
$$\begin{aligned}
f(X) &= y^T X y + z^T X^{-1} z - \log\det(X) \\
     &= \langle yy^T, X \rangle + \langle zz^T, X^{-1} \rangle - \log\det(X)
\end{aligned}$$
then the gradient is
$$\nabla f(X) = yy^T - X^{-1} zz^T X^{-1} - X^{-1}$$
I'd consider just doing a gradient descent with a backtracking line search to start. Because our variable is a matrix instead of a vector, it takes a bit of care to get the computations right, but it's not too bad. There are plenty of good explanations of gradient descent with backtracking line search available with a simple Google search. In short:

1. Compute $V=-\nabla f(X)$.
2. Find $t>0$ such that $f(X+tV)=f(X)-\tfrac{1}{2}t \|V\|_F^2$
3. Update $X\leftarrow X + tV$ and repeat

To find $t$, one typically just starts with $t=t_\max$ (say, 1) and cuts in half until the condition is satisfied. Again, Google is your friend.

Comment: Note that I'm arguing against my own interests here, given that I wrote CVX ;-) But I do think that there's rarely a benefit to solving an unconstrained problem with CVX when a smooth approach can work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample Matlab code that uses CVX to solve a problem similar to yours.  However, I don't yet know how to handle the $r^T X^{-1} r$ term.

```
N = 30;
y = randn(N,1);

cvx_begin sdp

    variable X hermitian
    minimize(.5*y'*X*y - log_det(X))
    subject to
        X >= 0

cvx_end
```

Comment: I guess I cannot use $X^{-1}$ with cvx, is that so?

Comment: @littlO I used your example it doesn't work. It shows failed status

Comment: `matrix_frac(r,X)` gives you that missing term

Comment: You don't need `X >= 0`; that is implied by the `log_det` term, and by the `matrix_frac` term as well

Comment: Holy cow I just noticed this is 4.5 years old

Comment: @MichaelGrant Glad you saw it, I never knew about matrix_frac.

Comment: It was on the front page for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

This is a heuristic approach and will get you to a local optima. From comments of OP, I understand that the objective is $$f(X)=y^TXy+r^TX^{-1}r+\log(\det(X))$$ Since $X$ is positive definite, $X$ can be decomposed as $U\Sigma U^T$ where $U$ is a orthonormal matrix of eigenvectors and $\Sigma$ is the diagonal matrix containing the singular values. Thus an heuristic approach would be to alternatively optimize the objective between $U$ and $\Sigma$. This means that we optimize the objective on one variable while fixing the other and then continue this. Note that this is a heuristic approach with no guarantees of global convergence. Now define $Y=yy^T$ and $R=rr^T$. Convince yourself of the following $$y^TXy=\mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma  U^TYU)$$where $\mathrm{Tr}$ is trace of a matrix. Also $$r^TX^{-1}r=\mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1}  U^TRU)$$ and $$\log(\det(X))=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\log\sigma_i$$ where $\sigma_i=[\Sigma]_{ii}$ are the singular values. Define $Y_u=U^TYU$ and $R_u=U^TRU$. Then fixing $U$, the objective becomes a function of singular values given as $$f(\sigma_i)=\sum_{i=1}^N\sigma_i[Y_u]_{ii}+{1\over \sigma_i}[Y_r]_{ii}+\log(\sigma_i)$$ and the minimization problem is $$\min_{\sigma_i}f(\sigma_i) \\ \sigma_i>0$$ It shouldn't be hard to reduce this further and find solutions for $\sigma_i$. Now fixing the singular values, the objective becomes $$f(U)=\mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma  U^TYU)+\mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1}  U^TRU)$$ and optimization problem is $$\min_{U}f(U) \\s.t.~~U^TU=I$$ This is a well-studied problem referred to as optimization with orthogonality constraints in literature. Please search for papers in this. You might even find existing packages that do this. Thus alternating between $U$ and $\Sigma$ will get you a local optima for $X$.